# What is the infrared controller in Nook Simple touch?

Tags: infrared, display, e-ink

I got an old Nook Simple Touch from my brother and it worked before. But it has been covered with mold so I removed the plastic case and it still boots, but cannot respond to any of my touch.
I found some kind of infrared grid touchscreen on the front of the motherboard, like this (I got the image from [here](https://www.ifixit.com/Teardown/Nook+Simple+Touch+with+GlowLight+Teardown/9301)):
[image: Image 1]
I think it needs the case or something to control the light direction. But I have already thrown the case away in the trash!

So my question is: How can I make it worked again, and if I can't, what is the infrared controller IC and how can I use it to emulate a touch or at least its datasheet?

I thought of somehow simulating the touch by connecting peers of IR transmitter and receiver together by a wire, but it didn't work.

I think this question is more suitable for the Electronic StackExchange than [Ebook StackExchange](https://ebooks.stackexchange.com/), so sorry if not.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: try using the device in a dark room ... or try using cardboard to exclude extraneous light ... lay a sheet of cardboard over the device ... the cardboard should have a 1 cm hole near the middle ... insert your finger through the cardboard

Comment: Can you add some images? Thanks!

Comment: there are no images ... use your imagination... get an empty breakfast cereal box ... cut out the whole front or back ... that is a fairly large piece of cardboard ... make a 1 cm hole in the middle ... lay the cardboard on top of the board in the picture ... poke your finger through the hole

Comment: @jsotola Ok thanks! I will try it. But will it respond only to that location?

Comment: don't be thinking about 143 touch points until you determine whether you can activate one